# What is the default track view instance?

Tags: tracking

I am writing a plugin that has some part tha shows how many times an entry is viewed.

However, I wouldn't know the track_view instance in advance.

I tried looking at the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/entry_tracking.html) but there is no indication which is the default.

What is the default track view instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is not to track at all. It is purely reliant on the [track_view](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/entry_tracking.html) parameter.

If your plugin always resides inside channel:entries tag, you could attempt to access the TMPL class itself and see if you can access the parameters used for the channel:entries (which will define which track_view is used). Alternatively package the plugin with an extension which hooks into the channel entries to get the parameter - but bit overkill.

Otherwise you could pass the entry_id to the plugin and then read the database to see which track_view has a number and assume that (although not 100% reliable as they may use multiple track_views for different purposes).

Comment: Barring plugins for a moment, if I use {exp:channel:entries} tag, there is no way to determine if views are tracked or not inside that tag then?

Comment: Nope. track_views is a parameter that the channel class acts upon when processing and increments the view count. channel:entries provides the variables for displaying the view counts (e.g. {view_count_one}) - but won't tell you which should be used out of the 4 tracking variables. Look at http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/simple-tracker which does what you want, but again you as the developer have to define which track variable to display.

Comment: Ok, that explanation is very helpful.